# How to iterate through web table with Selenium?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've been trying to iterate through this EV company table on Crunchbase but for some reason the code is only pulling up the first row. Any idea as to why ? Thanks ! :)

```
#imports
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time

#paths
PATH = "C:/Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.crunchbase.com/search/organizations/field/organization.companies/categories/electric-vehicle")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)
print(driver.title)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located(
          (By.XPATH, ('/html/body/chrome/div/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/div/search/page-layout/div/div/form/div[2]/results/div/div/div[3]/sheet-grid/div/div/grid-body/div/grid-row[1]/grid-cell[2]/div/field-formatter/identifier-formatter/a/div/div')
        )))

companies = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.identifier-label")

#create company dictionary and iterate through Crunchbase EV company table             
company_list = []
                          
for company in companies:
    name = company.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/chrome/div/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/div/search/page-layout/div/div/form/div[2]/results/div/div/div[3]/sheet-grid/div/div/grid-body/div/grid-row[1]/grid-cell[2]/div/field-formatter/identifier-formatter/a/div/div').text
    industry = company.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/chrome/div/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/div/search/page-layout/div/div/form/div[2]/results/div/div/div[3]/sheet-grid/div/div/grid-body/div/grid-row[1]/grid-cell[3]/div/field-formatter/identifier-multi-formatter/span').text
    hq = company.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/chrome/div/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/div/search/page-layout/div/div/form/div[2]/results/div/div/div[3]/sheet-grid/div/div/grid-body/div/grid-row[1]/grid-cell[4]/div/field-formatter/identifier-multi-formatter/span').text
    cblist = {
        'name': name,
        'industry': industry,
        'hq': hq
    }
    company_list.append(cblist)
#create dataframe    
df = pd.DataFrame(company_list)
print(df)
```

Comment: better use `relative` xpath. And try to use `classes` and `ids` to make xpath much shorter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should get all `grid-row` to get all rows in table and later you should use relative xpath (starting with `.`) to search only in selected row.

```
all_rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("grid-row")

all_companies = []
                          
for row in all_rows:
    company = {
        'name':     row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@class="identifier-label"]').text.strip(),
        'industry': row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-columnid="categories"]//span').text.strip(),
        'hq':       row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-columnid="location_identifiers"]//span').text.strip(),
        'cb rank':  row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-columnid="rank_org"]').text.strip(),
    }
    all_companies.append(company)
```

You should also learn to use `class`, `id` and any other unique values - ie. `data-columnid`.

---

Full working code

```
#imports
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time

#paths
PATH = "C:/Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
#driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = "https://www.crunchbase.com/search/organizations/field/organization.companies/categories/electric-vehicle"
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)

print('title:', driver.title)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located(
          (By.XPATH, ('//grid-body//identifier-formatter/a/div/div')
        )))

all_rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("grid-row")

all_companies = []
                          
for row in all_rows:
    company = {
        'name':     row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@class="identifier-label"]').text.strip(),
        'industry': row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-columnid="categories"]//span').text.strip(),
        'hq':       row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-columnid="location_identifiers"]//span').text.strip(),
        'cb rank':  row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-columnid="rank_org"]').text.strip(),
    }
    all_companies.append(company)
    
#create dataframe    
df = pd.DataFrame(all_companies)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough suggestions & explanation w/ minimal changes to my code ! :)

Comment: I tried to add the cb rank on the webpage using the datacolumn-id tag and for some reason it didn't work...any idea as to why ?

Comment: I don't know what exactly you try but it has to be `data-columnid`, not `datacolumn-id`. If you have new problem then create new question on new page - you will have more place for code and description. Eventually append it at the end of current question

Comment: this works for me `'.//*[@data-columnid="rank_org"]'`. I add it to answer.

Comment: got it. I did that, it works ! question: why didnt you include "//span" for the rank?

Comment: value is NOT in `<span>` but in `<a>`. With `//span` I would get empty string. I should  use `//a` to better describe place but even without `//a` it get text from all elements in this cell and there is only number.

Comment: any chance you can check out the new question I posted regarding this code ? Your explanations are good

Answer (score 1):

Increase grid-row index for each iteration within for loop in all identifiers like..

```
row_index = row_index + 1

name = company.find_element_by_xpath(
        '/html/body/chrome/div/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/div/search/page-layout/div/div/form/div[2]/results/div/div/div[3]/sheet-grid/div/div/grid-body/div/grid-row['+str(row_index)+']/grid-cell[2]/div/field-formatter/identifier-formatter/a/div/div').text
```